# How to know if Facebook redirected to my site (Facebook PHP SDK)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I try to integrate with facebook for login using facebook PHP SDK

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
"scope" => "email,name",
"next" => "http://localhost/provider/facebook/auth?is_facebook=$someurl",
));
```

But I don't get `is_facebook`  param when facebook redirects to my site. My guestion is how to know if its Facebook that redirected to my site

Answer (score 1):

A better way to see if a user came from Facebook would be to look at the HTTP referrer. You can do something like:

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) && strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'facebook.com' ) ) {
    echo 'User came from facebook';
}
```

This way, even if the GET variable is lost somewhere, you'll still know that the user came from Facebook. You can use this along with the `is_facebook=true` for extra validation.

Answer (score 0):

You would just set `is_facebook=true` or similar, in this case.  Since you're explicitly setting it here, Facebook will redirect to that URL and you will know that the user came from Facebook... or that they copied and pasted a URL.

You cannot rely on this for any security reason, but for general analytics, it is good enough.

Comment: like how can it can cause an security issue?

Comment: @user3311313 I don't know, that depends on what you're doing with the data.  If you had some area where you only allowed Facebook users in, and they could just put `?is_facebook=true` in the URL, that would be a problem.

Comment: my guestion is i get is_facebook param when it succeeds but i get different params when someting go wrong is there a common param i can check for error?

Comment: You need to use the PHP SDK to see if authentication succeeded or not.

Comment: I use PHP SDK I get is_facebook param when authentication succeeded but i dont get it when it fails

Comment: You need to call getUser() to see if it failed.

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" is not on internet network (hence can't be located), so you won't recieve the response.

Comment: This isn't true.  Facebook can still redirect to it.